# Oldest file in a directory - including all its sub directories using php

Tags: php, file

I need to find the oldest file in a directory, oldest file in all (including, directories, subdirectories of a particular folder)

```
   Folder 1
       - dir 1
          -  dir 1.1
             - file 1
       - dir 2
          - dir 2.1
             - file 2
```

if file 2 is oldest , I need to able to get oldest file (file 2) by passing main directory name (Folder 1)

my solutions is

```
    function get_oldest_file($dir) {
    $filemdate = array();
    print $dir.PHP_EOL;
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
     while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          $files[] = $file;
      print $file.PHP_EOL;
    }
    foreach ($files as $eachfile) {
        if (is_file($dir.eachfile)) {
          $file_date[$eachfile] = filemtime($dir.$eachfile);
          print $filemdate[$eachfile].PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
closedir($handle);
asort($filemdate, SORT_NUMERIC);
reset($filmdate);
$oldest = key($filemdate);
print "Oldest is : ".$oldest;
return $oldest;
}

 echo get_oldest_file("/path/---")
```

Thanks !

Comment: ok... And what is the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about?

```
function workerFunction($currentDir, $oldestFile)
    foreach (glob($currentDir.'/*') as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            if ((basename($file)!='.') && (basename($file)!='..')) {
                 $oldestFile = workerFunction($file, $oldestFile);
            }
        } else {
            $mtime = filemtime($file);
            if ($mtime <= $oldestFile['mtime']) {
                $oldestFile['mtime'] = $mtime;
                $oldestFile['path'] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    return $oldestFile;
}


function searchForOldestFile($dir) {
    $oldestFile['mtime'] = time();
    $oldestFile['path'] = null;
    $oldestFile = workerFunction($dir, $oldestFile);
    return $olderstFile['path'];
}
```

I don't have the PHP environment for debugging, but at least with some little fixes it could work as you need.
Let me explain, so you would be able to use it easily:
searchForOldestFile function is the interface that your script should call; workerFunction does the "magic" (if it work :)), keeping in $oldestFile a reference to the current oldestFile.